# Using SSIS to export SQL result output onto different excel worksheet based different criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a pre_defined configuration table contains unique list of query with the column of ID(identity column), Category and Query.

I need to create a SSIS package to loop through each query record and exec the query to populate the result output and the same time export the output onto multiple worksheet in one excel file. Based on what defined in Category column, the worksheet tab will be named as is.

For example, the query can be pre-defined as below:

```
   SELECT PAYOR_TYPE, FISCAL_YEAR, SUM(NET_REVENUE) FROM STND_ENCOUNTER

   SELECT PAYOR_TYPE, FISCAL_YEAR, SUM(GROSS_CHARGES) FROM STND_ENCOUNTER

   SELECT PATIENT_TYPE, PAYOR_TYPE, FISCAL_YEAR, SUM(NET_REVENUE) FROM STND_ENCOUNTER

   SELECT PATIENT_TYPE, SERVICE_LINE, FISCAL_YEAR, SUM(NET_REVENUE) FROM STND_ENCOUNTER
   .......
```

Please provide the method to build this package.  Thanks a lot

Comment: Do the query's all contain the same number of columns with the same data types? If not, then you will have to work with dynamic columns and create script tasks. Kind of ugly. You might be better off just creating several data flows, one for each query.

Comment: Hi Jody, each row of query maybe contains different number of columns. That's why this become tricky to do. Also, I thought about your idea which is creating several data flow task , but what happen if I have 100 or 200 rows of different query? Please provide advice.  Thanks